# Why doesn't the Ajax call work after a certain part of the code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a code in PHP and JS, where I use Vis.js to create a timeline and AJAX to make requests to a page to get a page as a response and put it inside a Bootstrap Modal.

Each user has an ID (in the div where the photo is) that when clicked opens the modal along with the page that was brought by the AJAX request. Until then, everything is fine. All AJAX requests to users work, the problem is with the timeline items.

Each item should do the same thing as clicking on the user ID, but bring up a different page. Up to item 6 works perfectly, however, after that, when I click on item 7 onwards nothing happens. The number of users is also above 6, but one call works and the other does not.

Does anyone have any idea why?

This is the code:

```
<script>

var now = Date.now();

var options = {
  stack: true,
  maxHeight: 640,
  horizontalScroll: true,
  verticalScroll: true,
  zoomKey: "ctrlKey",
  start: '2022-01-01',
  end: '2022-12-31',
  orientation: {
    axis: "top",
    item: "top",
  },
};

var groups = new vis.DataSet();
var items = new vis.DataSet();

var count = 300;

<?php

$query_todos = 'SELECT * FROM booking';
$todos_booking = $conn->prepare($query_todos);
$todos_booking->execute();

$combined = array();
$i = 0;

function sort_by_name($a,$b)
{
    return $a["nome_social"] > $b["nome_social"];
}

while($todos = $todos_booking->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

  $query_nome = 'SELECT nomesocial, foto, situacao FROM dados WHERE iddados =:id_funcionario';
  $nome = $conn->prepare($query_nome);
  $nome->bindParam(':id_funcionario', $todos['id_funcionario'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $nome->execute();

  $nome_social = $nome->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if(!empty($nome_social['foto'])){
    $img = $nome_social['foto'];
  }else{
    $img = '../img/avatar.png';
  }

    if( ( $key = array_search( $todos['id_funcionario'], array_column( $combined, 'id_funcionario') ) ) !== false )  {
      $combined[$key]['projeto'] .= '||'.$todos['projeto'];
      $combined[$key]['software'] .= '|||'.$todos['software'];
      $combined[$key]['data_inicio'] .= '||'.$todos['data_inicio'];
      $combined[$key]['data_fim'] .= '||'.$todos['data_fim'];
      $combined[$key]['confirmacao'] .= '||'.$todos['confirmacao'];
      $combined[$key]['img'] = $img;
      $combined[$key]['nome_social'] = $nome_social['nomesocial'];
      $combined[$key]['situacao'] = $nome_social['situacao'];
    } else {
      $todos['img'] = $img;
      $todos['nome_social'] = $nome_social['nomesocial'];
      $todos['situacao'] = $nome_social['situacao'];
      $combined[] = $todos;
    }
  }

  $combined_nome_social = $combined;

  uasort($combined,"sort_by_name");

  foreach($combined as $chave => $valor){
?>

<?php

  if(!empty($valor['projeto'])){

    ?>

  groups.add({
    id: <?php echo $i; ?>,
    content: "<div id='<?php echo str_replace(' ', '',$valor['nome_social']); ?>' class='row justify-content-center cursor'><img src='<?php echo $valor['img']; ?>' style='width: 100px; height: 80px; border-radius: 100%;'><div class='row justify-content-center'><?php echo $valor['nome_social']; ?></div></div>",
    order: <?php echo $i; ?>,
    <?php if($valor['situacao'] == '0'){
       echo "style: 'background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)',
        className: 'red'"; 
       } ?>
  });

  <?php }else{ ?>
groups.add({
    id: <?php echo $i; ?>,
    content: "<div id='<?php echo str_replace(' ', '',$valor['nome_social']); ?>' class='row justify-content-center cursor'><img src='<?php echo $valor['img']; ?>' style='width: 100px; height: 80px; border-radius: 100%;'><div class='row justify-content-center'><?php echo $valor['nome_social']; ?></div></div>",
    order: <?php echo $i; ?>,
    <?php if($valor['situacao'] == '0'){
       echo "style: 'background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)',
       className: 'red'"; 
       } ?>
  });

  <?php } ?>

  setTimeout(function(){

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#<?php echo str_replace(' ', '',$valor['nome_social']); ?>").click(function(){
    $("#editar_funcionario").html('');
    $.ajax({
          url: '../utilities/modal_adicionar_booking.php?id_funcionario=<?php echo $valor['id_funcionario']; ?>',
          method: 'GET',
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          success: function(resultado){
  $form = $("<form id='adicionar_funcionario_booking' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'></form>");
  $("#editar_funcionario").append($form);
  $("#adicionar_funcionario_booking").html(resultado);
  $("#titulo_editar").html('Adicionar booking de <?php echo $valor['nome_social']; ?>');
  let el = document.getElementById('editar');
  let modal =new bootstrap.Modal(el);
  modal.show();

  let confirmacao = document.getElementById('confirmacao');

  confirmacao.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  if(confirmacao.checked){
      document.getElementById('label_confirmacao').innerHTML = "Confirmado";
  }else{
      document.getElementById('label_confirmacao').innerHTML = "Não confirmado";
  }
})

$("#botao_salvar").click(function(){
    $('#botao_salvar').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#botao_salvar').html('');
        $('#botao_salvar').append('<img src="../img/loading.gif" style="width: 30px;"/>');
    var dados = new FormData(document.getElementById("adicionar_funcionario_booking"));
      $.ajax({
            url: '../utilities/adicionar_booking.php?id_funcionario=<?php echo $valor['id_funcionario']; ?>',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: dados,
            success: function(resultado){
              let erros = ['erro_data_inicio', 'erro_data_fim'];
              let erros_select = ['erro_projeto', 'erro_software'];
              for (let i = 0; i < erros.length; i++) { 
                if((resultado[erros[i]]) && (resultado[erros[i]] != 'vazio')){
                $('#'+erros[i]).html(resultado[erros[i]]);
                $('#'+erros[i].replace('erro_', '')).removeClass();
                $('#'+erros[i].replace('erro_', '')).addClass('invalido form-control');

                $('#'+erros[i].replace('erro_', '')).on('input', ()=> {
                    $('#'+erros[i].replace('erro_', '')).removeClass();
                    $('#'+erros[i].replace('erro_', '')).addClass('form-control');
                    $('#'+erros[i]).html('');
                })
                }
              }
              for (let i = 0; i < erros_select.length; i++) {                 
                    if((resultado[erros_select[i]]) && (resultado[erros_select[i]] != 'vazio')){
                    $('#'+erros_select[i]).html(resultado[erros_select[i]]);
                    $('#'+erros_select[i].replace('erro_', '')+'_chosen').removeClass();
                    $('#'+erros_select[i].replace('erro_', '')+'_chosen').addClass('invalido chosen-container chosen-container-multi');
    
                    $('#'+erros_select[i].replace('erro_', '')).on('input', ()=> {
                        $('#'+erros_select[i].replace('erro_', '')+'_chosen').removeClass();
                        $('#'+erros_select[i].replace('erro_', '')+'_chosen').addClass('chosen-container chosen-container-multi');
                        $('#'+erros_select[i]).html('');
                    })
                    }
                    }
                    if(resultado.status){
                    modal.hide();
                    let status = document.createElement('div');
                    status.setAttribute("id", 'status');
                    document.body.appendChild(status);
                    $('#status').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top':'0', 'width':'100%', 'z-index':'100', 'text-align': 'center', 'color':'white', 'padding':'10px 10px 10px 10px', 
                    'font-size': '17px', 'background':'#0a5a0a'});
                    let progresso = document.createElement('span');
                    progresso.classList.add('progress-bar-fill');
                    progresso.style.cssText = 'width: 0%;';
                    $('#status').html(resultado.status);
                    document.getElementById('status').appendChild(progresso);
                    $('.progress-bar-fill').delay(50).queue(function () {
                        $(this).css('width', '100%')
                    });
                    setTimeout(() =>{
                        window.location.reload();
                    }, 1000);
                    $('#botao_salvar').remove();
                }
                $('#botao_salvar img:last-child').remove();
                $('#botao_salvar').html('Salvar alterações');
                $('#botao_salvar').prop('disabled', false);
            }
      })
    })

waitForElm('.chosen-select-software').then((elm) => {
      setTimeout(() =>{
    $.getScript('../bootstrap/_bootstrap/js/chosen_software.jquery.min.js', function() {
      console.debug('Script loaded.');
    });
    $.getScript('../bootstrap/_bootstrap/js/projeto_booking.js', function() {
      console.debug('Script loaded.');
    });
  }, 250);
});

}
})
})
})
}, 1000);

<?php
  $itens = explode('||', $valor['projeto']);
  $softwares = explode('|||', $valor['software']);
  $inicio = explode('||', $valor['data_inicio']);
  $fim = explode('||', $valor['data_fim']);
  $confirmacao = explode('||', $valor['confirmacao']);

  for($x = 0; $x < count($itens); $x++){

?>
  var start = '<?php echo $inicio[$x]; ?>';
  var end = '<?php echo $fim[$x]; ?>';

  <?php

  if(!empty($valor['projeto'])){

    ?>

  items.add({
    group: <?php echo $i; ?>,
    start: start,
    end: end,
    type: "range",
    content: "<div id='<?php $word = array_merge(range('a', 'z'), range('A', 'Z')); shuffle($word); $aleatorio = substr(implode($word), 0, 100); echo $aleatorio; ?>' title=' Projeto: <?php echo $itens[$x]; ?>&#10;Software: <?php echo str_replace('||', ', ', $softwares[$x]); ?>&#10;início: <?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($inicio[$x])); ?>&#10;fim: <?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($fim[$x])); ?>'><?php if($confirmacao[$x] == '0'){echo '<img src=\'../img/nao_confirmado.png\' style=\'width: 17px;\'><br>';}else{echo '<img src=\'../img/confirmado.png\' style=\'width: 17px;\'><br>';} ?><?php echo $itens[$x].'<br>'.str_replace('||', ', ', $softwares[$x]); ?></div>",
    className: '<?php echo $itens[$x]; ?>',
  });  


  $(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#<?php echo $aleatorio; ?>").click(function(){

      editarBooking();

    })

      function editarBooking(){
      $("#editar_funcionario").html('');
      $.ajax({
            url: '../utilities/modal_editar_booking.php?id_funcionario=<?php echo $valor['id_funcionario']; ?>&projeto=<?php echo $itens[$x]; ?>&data_inicio=<?php echo $inicio[$x]; ?>&data_fim=<?php echo $fim[$x]; ?>&software=<?php echo $softwares[$x]; ?>&confirmacao=<?php echo $confirmacao[$x]; ?>',
            method: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(resultado){
    $form = $("<form id='editar_funcionario_booking' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'></form>");
    $("#editar_funcionario").append($form);
    $("#editar_funcionario_booking").html(resultado);
    $("#titulo_editar").html('Editar booking de <?php echo $valor['nome_social']; ?>');
    let el = document.getElementById('editar');
    let modal =new bootstrap.Modal(el);
    modal.show();

    let confirmacao = document.getElementById('confirmacao');

    confirmacao.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    if(confirmacao.checked){
        document.getElementById('label_confirmacao').innerHTML = "Confirmado";
    }else{
        document.getElementById('label_confirmacao').innerHTML = "Não confirmado";
    }
})

  $("#botao_salvar").click(function(){
    $('#botao_salvar').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#botao_salvar').html('');
        $('#botao_salvar').append('<img src="../img/loading.gif" style="width: 30px;"/>');
    var dados = new FormData(document.getElementById("editar_funcionario_booking"));
      $.ajax({
            url: '../utilities/editar_booking.php?id_funcionario=<?php echo $valor['id_funcionario']; ?>&projeto=<?php echo $itens[$x]; ?>&data_inicio=<?php echo $inicio[$x]; ?>&data_fim=<?php echo $fim[$x]; ?>&software=<?php echo $softwares[$x]; ?>&confirmacao=<?php echo $confirmacao[$x]; ?>',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: dados,
            success: function(resultado){
              let erros = ['erro_data_inicio', 'erro_data_fim'];
              let erros_select = ['erro_projeto', 'erro_software'];
              for (let i = 0; i < erros.length; i++) { 
                if((resultado[erros[i]]) && (resultado[erros[i]] != 'vazio')){
                $('#'+erros[i]).html(resultado[erros[i]]);
                $('#'+erros[i].replace('erro_', '')).removeClass();
                $('#'+erros[i].replace('erro_', '')).addClass('invalido form-control');

                $('#'+erros[i].replace('erro_', '')).on('input', ()=> {
                    $('#'+erros[i].replace('erro_', '')).removeClass();
                    $('#'+erros[i].replace('erro_', '')).addClass('form-control');
                    $('#'+erros[i]).html('');
                })
                }
              }
              for (let i = 0; i < erros_select.length; i++) {                 
                    if((resultado[erros_select[i]]) && (resultado[erros_select[i]] != 'vazio')){
                    $('#'+erros_select[i]).html(resultado[erros_select[i]]);
                    $('#'+erros_select[i].replace('erro_', '')+'_chosen').removeClass();
                    $('#'+erros_select[i].replace('erro_', '')+'_chosen').addClass('invalido chosen-container chosen-container-multi');
    
                    $('#'+erros_select[i].replace('erro_', '')).on('input', ()=> {
                        $('#'+erros_select[i].replace('erro_', '')+'_chosen').removeClass();
                        $('#'+erros_select[i].replace('erro_', '')+'_chosen').addClass('chosen-container chosen-container-multi');
                        $('#'+erros_select[i]).html('');
                    })
                    }
                    }
                    if(resultado.status){
                    modal.hide();
                    let status = document.createElement('div');
                    status.setAttribute("id", 'status');
                    document.body.appendChild(status);
                    $('#status').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top':'0', 'width':'100%', 'z-index':'100', 'text-align': 'center', 'color':'white', 'padding':'10px 10px 10px 10px', 
                    'font-size': '17px', 'background':'#0a5a0a'});
                    let progresso = document.createElement('span');
                    progresso.classList.add('progress-bar-fill');
                    progresso.style.cssText = 'width: 0%;';
                    $('#status').html(resultado.status);
                    document.getElementById('status').appendChild(progresso);
                    $('.progress-bar-fill').delay(50).queue(function () {
                        $(this).css('width', '100%')
                    });
                    setTimeout(() =>{
                        window.location.reload();
                    }, 1000);
                    $('#botao_salvar').remove();
                }
                $('#botao_salvar img:last-child').remove();
                $('#botao_salvar').html('Salvar alterações');
                $('#botao_salvar').prop('disabled', false);
            }
      })
    })

    waitForElm('.chosen-select-software').then((elm) => {
      setTimeout(() =>{
    $.getScript('../bootstrap/_bootstrap/js/chosen_software.jquery.min.js', function() {
      console.debug('Script loaded.');
    });
    $.getScript('../bootstrap/_bootstrap/js/projeto_booking.js', function() {
      console.debug('Script loaded.');
    });
  }, 250);
});
    }
  })
}
})}, 1000);

<?php }else{ ?>

  items.add({
    group: <?php echo $i; ?>,
    start: '<?php echo  date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-4 month', strtotime(date('Y-m-d')))); ?>',
    end: '<?php echo  date('Y-m-d'); ?>',
    content: '<div class="row justify-content-center">NENHUMA INFORMAÇÃO DE BOOKING ENCONTRADA</div>',
  });  


<?php
}
}
$i++;
}
?>


// create a Timeline
var container = document.getElementById("booking");
timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, null, options);
timeline.setGroups(groups);
timeline.setItems(items);

function debounce(func, wait = 100) {
  let timeout;
  return function (...args) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      func.apply(this, args);
    }, wait);
  };
}

function move(percentage) {
  var range = timeline.getWindow();
  var interval = range.end - range.start;

  timeline.setWindow({
    start: range.start.valueOf() - interval * percentage,
    end: range.end.valueOf() - interval * percentage,
  });
}

document.getElementById("zoomIn").onclick = function () {
  timeline.zoomIn(0.5);
};
document.getElementById("zoomOut").onclick = function () {
  timeline.zoomOut(0.5);
};
document.getElementById("moveLeft").onclick = function () {
  move(0.2);
};
document.getElementById("moveRight").onclick = function () {
  move(-0.2);
};

function waitForElm(selector) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            return resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
        }

        const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
            if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
                resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
                observer.disconnect();
            }
        });

        observer.observe(document.body, {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

This is the timeline:

[timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znnlX.png)

Comment: What steps have you taken to debug this?  On the client side you have the F12 developer tools that will show you any JavaScript errors and will let you look at the request and response traffic.  In PHP you can add extra debugging code and turn on errors and warnings,  In PHP if something unexpected happens you can also echo some information then exit to return an error page.

Comment: First of all thanks for taking the time to answer me :)

No error is shown in both JS and PHP.

Comment: If there is no error, then there is a flaw in the logic.  Add logging to both sides, click on item 7, look at the logging to figure out what part of the code does not work the way that you expect it to.  You can also just trace through the code in your mind plugging in item 7's values and look at how each step will run.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs it, I'll leave the solution here, even if I find it difficult for someone to need it.

After a lot of breaking my head doing tests, I realized the following:

Items are only created as the scroll goes down and the groups appear.

That is, when I put the events for items that are not visible on the screen, they were not created, so there is no way to call the event, because its ID does not exist yet.

The solution was to use the MutationObserver API to check when the element exists on the page and apply a function to it.

```
<script>
   function waitForElm(selector) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            return resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
        }

        const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
            if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
                resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
                observer.disconnect();
            }
        });

        observer.observe(document.body, {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: A more effective solution would be to bind the event to a parent element that doesn't go away. (otherwise known as event delegation.) Yet another better option (not as good as delegation) would be to bind the event at the point in time you add the element, rather than waiting for the observer to realize you added an element.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea, however I don't have access to the parent element as it is created by a JS file called "timeline.min.js". Unless I have to change it to put a dynamic ID in that div. What do you advise?

Comment: You could always go yet another parent up.

Comment: Truth. I hadn't thought about that. Thank you again.